# How to bypass C# selenium website security protection?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

[image: Security Protection]

I have no idea how to circumvent the security protection you see above.

It opens when I enter it manually. Does not open when entered automatically

Comment: You have to disable Captcha, Two-factor authentication and other security tools against the automation when you apply the Selenium tests

Comment: Can you write in the answer how to do this?

Comment: It should be configured somehow on your side. So it is a bit hard to guess. You need to know what exactly are you using. For such popular things like Cloudfare there should be proper tutorials and articles like https://community.cloudflare.com/t/turn-off-browser-integrity-check-for-load-testing/92723/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddAdditionalCapability("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
options.AddArgument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.AddArgument (
    "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")
options.AddArgument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
var driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("window.open('https://www.paribu.com/')");
    
ReadOnlyCollection<string> windowHandles = driver.WindowHandles;  
driver.SwitchTo().Window(windowHandles[0])
driver.close()
driver.SwitchTo().Window(windowHandles [1])
```

This you can disable the automation flags and use win.open to open the website . Else redirects will be blocked and the website detects the automation script